# What are the best LaTeX editor/compiler?

Tags: software-recommendation, latex

I'm looking for a LaTeX editor/compiler that does not show the output until it is done.
It can be in terminal or not, I don't care.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5701

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you want here. Editing without seeing the (formatted) output can be done with any text editor. And compiling never shows the output, just creates the output file. If what you want is not seeing output during compilation, simply redirect the output (`latex file.tex >/dev/null 2>&1`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't quite understand what you meant by 'editor/compiler that does not show the output until it is done'. However, I'd suggest Kile. It is the only one which gave me output despite any unmet library dependency. I've tried a few others without success, even on Windows 7 (although some seem to work excellently on Windows XP).

Install kile with the command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kile
```

Comment: I meant that I want to edit the hole thing and then compile it. I've heard that some compilers show you a preview, or you edit like MsWord and I don't want that. I'll try Kile, thank you.

Comment: You can open one editor in one workspace and output in other. Edit .tex file, compile it and then see the output in the next workspace. Convenient arrangement.

Comment: Kile is currently deprecated

Answer (score 8):

[Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) is a very good cross-platform LaTeX editor. Installation link: [Texmaker](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/texmaker) [image: Install texmaker]

Answer (score 5):

What I like about [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) with the [gedit-latex-plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gedit-latex/) is that you can configure your own snippets with shortcuts. For example, if you use `\mbox{text}` often, you generate a snippet `\mbox{$}` with the shortcut tab-mb, so you just have to type tab-mb to have the mbox latex command with the cursor positioned in the place where you placed the $ in the snippet.

[image: gedit with gedit-latex-plugin and the snippet window]

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-latex-plugin
```

Comment: `gedit` + `gedit-latex-plugin` + `syntex` + `evince` is the perfect combination.

Comment: [gedit is very slow and/or crashes when opening files with very long lines. Can you fix it? (...) This is a known limitation (...) and cannot be fixed.](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/FAQ) *if* you can live with that, gedit may be for you; else, you may want to look for other options, e.g. [geany](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Vim-LaTeX.  The pros are user-defined macros as well as many convenient pre-defined hotkeys in addition to the pluses of Vim (efficient text editor).  The cons are the cons of Vim (weird text editor) plus the fact that the package is pretty raw looking.  Vim is just a text editor, so although the Vim-LaTeX addon adds extra commands and menus, there are no point-and-click graphical shortcuts--and there is no document outline until the pdf is produced.  In all, I've come to enjoy it....

Answer (score 2):

https://www.texstudio.org is the best editor for me in Linux.

```
sudo apt install texstudio
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [RTextDoc](http://jwork.org/rtextdoc) LaTeX editor. It runs on Ubuntu (since Java). Plus, unlike others, it has instant grammar checking.

Answer (score 1):

I use latex a lot both academically and professionally.

By far the best solution for me is [Latexila](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/LaTeXila).

It is open source, it's very simple! And have all features i need to edit latex (tex packages autocomplete, structure view, syntax highlight, syntax error notification, embedded compile button, spellchecking...

Install it with texlive pacakges using:
'sudo apt-get install latexila texlive'

---

My opinion of other editors.

- **[Kile](https://github.com/KDE/kile)**: Was a good editor 5 years ago. But now the project is abandoned. Lacks funcionalities and support. The DEV abandonaded and created TexMaker.
- **[TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html): Very good, it is the most complete nowadays, and it's open source. Nice alternative to Latexila.
- **Gedit/VIM/Plugin-based**: Personally, i think this is too much configuration, but don't give you a simple and seamless experience.