# Editing a Latex file after installing TexLive

Tags: 14.04, package-management, latex, texlive

I have just installed TexLive by running `sudo apt-get install texlive`. According to the official website, this package also comes with the editor TexWorks. But how do I now open a `.tex` file with TexWorks? If I right-click on a `.tex` file, TexWorks is not listed as one of the default applications. Furthermore, if I search for TexWorks on my machine, it cannot be found...

Comment: You have to install `texworks` separately. I have `texlive-full` installed and it didn't pull TexWorks. As an aside, TeXWorks is ok, but if you are just starting, I strongly advise you to start with a generic editor (`gedit` is ok) and by-hand compilation - steeper starting curve, better understanding later. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides and http://askubuntu.com/questions/214172/what-are-the-best-latex-editor-compiler (By the way, my personal choice is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252555/38080 )

Comment: Have you tried TeXStudio? `sudo apt-get install texstudio`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you should add TeXWorks explicitily, as in

```
sudo apt-get install texworks
```

You need to have the ["universe" repository enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

Long one: read my comment and browse the [relevant question in TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).