# cannot locate tex-live latex in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, texlive

I am new to using ubuntu. I have installed tex-live latex in ubuntu 16.04. But I cannot locate it. I'm interested in using latex beamer which is included in the texlive package. How can I find it and execute it. However, I'm sure that the packages is installed correctly, which I have verified using Synaptic Package Manager. Thanks

Comment: Have you already searched for "tex" in the dash?

Comment: Hello @Sreeram Udayan, as I understand it, tex-live is a library, so what you should do after having installed tex-live is to install a latex text editor in which you will write your latex code, for that you can have a look here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/214172/what-are-the-best-latex-editor-compiler.  My question to you is, how are you trying to "find" it? If you are using a simple text editor like gedit then the question is how are you compiling it? Personally I use Gummi as the text editor: https://technicalandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/how-to-install-gummi-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Lastly, What do you get when you run: `which tex` and 
`latex -version`?

Comment: Hi Thanks. Yes you're absolutely right. The problem was I didn't install a proper text editor. I have installed texmaker and now things are running smooth. Cheers....